# How to implement Log4j2 custom layout yaml configuration

Tags: log4j2

I am using custom layout for log4j2 framework. How to specify custom layout in log4j2 yaml configuration file ? 
The sample I tried is given below. This does not work at the moment saying invalid element 'layout'.

```
Configutation:
  status: warn
  packages: uk.co.logging.layout

  Properties:
    Property:
      name: logging.dir
      value: ./default_log_dir/
    Property:
      name: service.name
      value: default

  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: CONSOLE
      layout: ConnectJsonLayout

      policies:
        TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          interval: 1
          modulate: true
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          size: 250MB
    RollingFile:
      - name: APPLICATION
        fileName: ${logging.dir}/${service.name}.log
        filePattern: ${logging.dir}/${date:yyyy-MM}/${service.name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
        layout: ConnectJsonLayout

        policies:
          TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            interval: 1
            modulate: true
          SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            size: 250MB

  Loggers:
      Root:
        level: error
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: CONSOLE
          - ref: APPLICATION
      Logger:
        - name: uk.co.xxx
          additivity: false
          level: debug
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: CONSOLE
            - ref: APPLICATION
```

Kind Regards,

Kiran

Comment: did you figure this out? I have the same issue. In XML you'd simply put `<ConnectJsonLayout/>` element in <RollingFile>, which translates to `ConnectJsonLayout:` element in `RollingFile:`; but i too get _invalid element_ error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Configutation:
  status: warn
  packages: uk.co.logging.layout

  Properties:
    Property:
      name: logging.dir
      value: ./default_log_dir/
    Property:
      name: service.name
      value: default

  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: CONSOLE
      ConnectJsonLayout: {}
  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: error
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: CONSOLE
```

Comment: Please add a description that explains your answer.

Comment: This works - above, "ConnectJsonLayout" is the name of the custom appender.  Equivalent of <ConnectJsonLayout/> in yaml is "ConnectJsonLayout: {}" - you have to assign it something.